# Delete items with checkbox

Tags: html, codeigniter

My question is how to configure the button to delete the titles, whose checkbox is checked, from my DB.

On my page i've displayed some Titles with checkboxes.

```
<?php 
                            foreach ($query as $row){ 
                            echo  '<tr><td><label class="checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="checkbox[]" value='.$row['link'].'>
                                </td><td>
                                '.'<a href='.$row['link'].'>'.$row['title'].'</a>'.'</td><td>'.substr($row['pub_date'], 5, 12).'</label></td>

                                </tr>'; 
                            } ?>
```

Here is the delete button.

```
<? echo form_open('site/delete');?>
                    <button type="submit"><i class="icon-trash"></i></button><br/><br/>
                    <? echo form_close();   ?>
```

The controller function

```
function delete()
    {
        $this->load->model('membership_model');
        $this->membership_model->delete_title();
    }
```

And the model

```
function delete_title()
    {
        $this->db->where(array('title' => ,'username'=>$this->session->userdata('username')));
        $this->db->delete('feeds');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need either an Ajax call or a form submit to a POST url.

Considering that I'm guessing you wish to remain on the same page while doing the delete, You'll need javascript Ajax call to the controller to call the delete functions.

The bulk of the solution is primarily javascript as you have the PHP backend all set-up already.

Here's a link to jquery's ajax documentation
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/